# "Textbox Listener"

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I am creating an application which contains text boxes on the left for user to input and on the right of the application , it contains number buttons (1 - 9 & back space)

How do i make my text boxes listen to those button so that when i click on the buttons on the right , it will add the numbers to the text boxes on the left. I try not to do the IF else statement as i find it not efficient.

I only need one textbox to be filled when clicking on the buttons on the right each time. 
Another question is , is there a code for "BackSpace" so that when I click backspace only 1 number gets delete on the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the click event from each of the buttons to update the content of the textboxes.